# Overriding the look of baked-in Android features

Tags: android, overriding, speech-recognition

The Android app I'm working on makes use of Android's baked-in speech-input feature, but I want to alter the look of the speech-input dialog to be more of an aesthetic match with the rest of my program. Is there a way to substitute my own assets?  Is it a simple matter of overriding the layout xml that the parent class references? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make a custom dialog and use setContentView(R.layout.something)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it is as easy as substituting a layout.

You need to manage your own speech recognition flow by using the [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class.

There's a lot of details involved in using it, but it appears that you can customize the UI experience if you can.